# sha256 incorrect output when the length is more than 56

Tags: python, hash, sha256

I'm trying to learn each step of sha256, so I wrote a code with python that uses the binary strings instead of math operations to fully understand it.

The code works fine when the input is less than 56 characters but when it's equal or more than 56 characters the output is incorrect:

For exmaple when the input is:
`ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223bda12ae1a5324sfdserew3ra`

instead of `1caa150674ab1aed030dc69f9b86dbcbc412e6e1dd20344eeaa21687acae7789`

I get `8492782cc396d4454980c9b63f127c5730da7d838822f8f37b1c7705d2630b88`

Code:

Operations.py

```
  class Operations:
        def add(self, data1, data2):
              x = data1
              y = data2

              carry = 0
              result = ""

              for i in range(len(data1) -1, -1, -1):
                    r = carry
                    r += 1 if x[i] == '1' else 0
                    r += 1 if y[i] == '1' else 0
                    result = ('1' if r % 2 == 1 else '0') + result
                    carry = 0 if r < 2 else 1

              if carry != 0: result = '1' + result

              return result[-len(data1):]

        def xor(self, data1, data2):
              result = ""
              for i in range(len(data1)):
                    temp1 = data1[i]
                    temp2 = data2[i]
                    if (temp1 == "0" and temp2 == "0") or (temp1 == "1" and temp2 == "1"):
                          result += "0"
                    else:
                          result += "1"

              return result

        def shiftRight(self, data, turn):
              result = "0" * turn + data
              return result[:len(data)]

        def rotateRight(self, data, turn):
              result = None
              for i in range(turn):
                    if result:
                          temp = result[-1]
                          result = (temp + result)[:len(data)]
                    else:
                          temp = data[-1]
                          result = (temp + data)[:len(data)]

              return result
```

---

Functions.py

```
  from operations import Operations

  class Functions(Operations):
        def sigma0(self, data): # Lowercase sigma
              temp1 = self.rotateRight(data, 7)
              temp2 = self.rotateRight(data, 18)
              temp3 = self.shiftRight(data, 3)
              result = self.xor(temp3, self.xor(temp1, temp2))
              return result

        def sigma1(self, data): # Lowercase sigma
              temp1 = self.rotateRight(data, 17)
              temp2 = self.rotateRight(data, 19)
              temp3 = self.shiftRight(data, 10)
              result = self.xor(temp3, self.xor(temp1, temp2))
              return result

        def gamma0(self, data): # Uppercase sigma
              temp1 = self.rotateRight(data, 2)
              temp2 = self.rotateRight(data, 13)
              temp3 = self.rotateRight(data, 22)
              result = self.xor(temp3, self.xor(temp1, temp2))
              return result

        def gamma1(self, data): # Uppercase sigma
              temp1 = self.rotateRight(data, 6)
              temp2 = self.rotateRight(data, 11)
              temp3 = self.rotateRight(data, 25)
              result = self.xor(temp3, self.xor(temp1, temp2))
              return result

        def choice(self, x, y, z):
              result = ""
              for i in range(len(x)):
                    result += y[i] if x[i] == "1" else z[i]

              return result

        def majority(self, x, y, z):
              result = ""
              for i in range(len(x)):
                    temp0 = 0
                    temp1 = 0

                    temp0 += 1 if x[i] == "0" else 0 
                    temp1 += 1 if x[i] == "1" else 0

                    temp0 += 1 if y[i] == "0" else 0                  
                    temp1 += 1 if y[i] == "1" else 0

                    temp0 += 1 if z[i] == "0" else 0
                    temp1 += 1 if z[i] == "1" else 0
                    
                    if temp0 > temp1:
                          result += "0"
                    else:
                          result += "1"

              return result
```

---

Main.py

```
  from math import ceil
  from copy import copy
  from functions import Functions

  _k = [0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5,
        0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
        0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3,
        0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
        0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc,
        0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
        0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7,
        0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
        0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13,
        0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
        0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3,
        0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
        0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5,
        0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
        0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208,
        0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2]

  _h = [0x6a09e667, 0xbb67ae85, 0x3c6ef372, 0xa54ff53a,
        0x510e527f, 0x9b05688c, 0x1f83d9ab, 0x5be0cd19]

  class SHA256(Functions):
        blocks = []

        def __init__(self):
              global _k, _h            
              _k = [f'{i:b}'.zfill(32) for i in _k]
              _h = [f'{i:b}'.zfill(32) for i in _h]

        def message_to_blocks(self, message):
              chunk = 56
              data = [format(ord(x), 'b').zfill(8) for x in message]

              for i in range(ceil(len(data) / chunk)):
                    self.blocks.append(data[chunk * i:chunk * (i + 1)])

                    self.blocks[i] = ''.join(self.blocks[i])
                    length = f'{len(self.blocks[i]):b}'
                    self.blocks[i] += '1'
                    self.blocks[i] = self.blocks[i].ljust(512, '0')

                    # add length to last 64 bit
                    self.blocks[i] = self.blocks[i][:-len(length)]
                    self.blocks[i] += length

        def message_schedule(self, data):
              schedule = []
              n = 32
              # first 16 words
              schedule = [(data[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(data), n)]
              # generate the rest
              for i in range(16, 64):
                    temp1 = self.sigma1(schedule[-2])
                    temp2 = self.sigma0(schedule[-15])
                    result = self.add(temp1, self.add(schedule[-7], self.add(temp2, schedule[-16])))
                    schedule.append(result)

              return schedule

        def compress(self):
              for block in self.blocks:
                    temp_h = copy(_h)
                    _w = self.message_schedule(block)
                    for i in range(64):
                          T1 = [self.gamma1(_h[4]), self.choice(_h[4], _h[5], _h[6]), _h[7], _k[i], _w[i]]
                          T1 = self.add(T1[0], self.add(T1[1], self.add(T1[2], self.add(T1[3], T1[4]))))

                          T2 = [self.gamma0(_h[0]), self.majority(_h[0], _h[1], _h[2])]
                          T2 = self.add(T2[0], T2[1])
                          
                          # shift all constants down
                          _h[7] = _h[6] # h
                          _h[6] = _h[5] # g
                          _h[5] = _h[4] # f
                          _h[4] = _h[3] # e
                          _h[3] = _h[2] # d
                          _h[2] = _h[1] # c
                          _h[1] = _h[0] # b

                          # compress
                          _h[0] = self.add(T1, T2)
                          _h[4] = self.add(_h[4], T1)

                    # add with initial values
                    _h[0] = self.add(_h[0], temp_h[0])
                    _h[1] = self.add(_h[1], temp_h[1])
                    _h[2] = self.add(_h[2], temp_h[2])
                    _h[3] = self.add(_h[3], temp_h[3])
                    _h[4] = self.add(_h[4], temp_h[4])
                    _h[5] = self.add(_h[5], temp_h[5])
                    _h[6] = self.add(_h[6], temp_h[6])
                    _h[7] = self.add(_h[7], temp_h[7])

              return self.digest(_h)

        def digest(self, hashes):
              final_hash = ""
              for hash in hashes:
                    t = hex(int(hash, 2))
                    final_hash += t[2:]

              return final_hash

  a = SHA256()
  a.message_to_blocks("ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223bda12ae1a5324sfdserew3ra")
  print(a.compress())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The code works fine when the input is less than 56 characters but when it's equal or more than 56 characters the output is incorrect

The problem is with this part:

```py
length = f'{len(self.blocks[i]):b}'
self.blocks[i] += '1'
self.blocks[i] = self.blocks[i].ljust(512, '0')
# add length to last 64 bit
self.blocks[i] = self.blocks[i][:-len(length)]
self.blocks[i] += length
```

The error is in the way the zero padding is calculated combined with the length not having a 64-bit width. As it is, your code pads the last message block with zeros so it will have a 512 bit length then replaces the last n-bits with the unpadded binary length (`111000000`), but this won't work correctly in cases where the zero padding is less than 64-bits.

The result of this is the code processes the total message input as:

`01100010011000010011011100111000 00110001001101100110001001100110 00111000011001100011000000110001 01100011011001100110010101100001 00110100001100010011010000110001 00110100001100000110010001100101 00110101011001000110000101100101 00110010001100100011001000110011 01100010011001000110000100110001 00110010011000010110010100110001 01100001001101010011001100110010 00110100011100110110011001100100 01110011011001010111001001100101 01110111001100110111001001100001 10000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000111000000`

Instead of:

`01100010011000010011011100111000 00110001001101100110001001100110 00111000011001100011000000110001 01100011011001100110010101100001 00110100001100010011010000110001 00110100001100000110010001100101 00110101011001000110000101100101 00110010001100100011001000110011 01100010011001000110000100110001 00110010011000010110010100110001 01100001001101010011001100110010 00110100011100110110011001100100 01110011011001010111001001100101 01110111001100110111001001100001 10000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000111000000`

Comment: so the length is the whole message length? I thought in each block we should specify the length of the message in the block.

Comment: @hamidreza The length is the total length in bits of the original message before any processing and it is only the final 512-bit block which has the length at the end. Basically the original message is processed in 512-bit chunks until there is no message remaining, then the '1' is appended, followed by however many zeroes are needed to make the 64-bit length end on a 512-bit boundary.